# The meaning of "normally"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"normally" sometimes mean "in normal situations". Other times in mean "in a normal manner". How not to make confusion between the to senses?

Example:

> In that case, doing A would **normally** refine one's situation.

Here by "normally" I mean "in normal situations". But in the above sentence "normally" can also mean "in a normal manner". How to remove such confusion?

Comment: You shouldn't define a word using the same word. In your example, it seems to mean *usually* or *in general*.

Comment: refine  one's situation?? Doesn't your native language distinguish adjectives from adverbs??

Comment: You have to see what word in the sentence it modifies.  In your example *normally* isn't used to say how you do something but rather when or why you do something, so it must mean "in normal situations".   Compare this with *"Would you stop being so weird and walk **normally**!"*

Answer (score 1):

You would distinguish this by word order.  If you are modifying *how* you do something ("in a normal manner"), you would put *normally* after the verb:

> Would you stop being silly and just eat your dinner **normally**!
>
> After her throat surgery, it took many months of therapy before she could talk **normally**, much less sing.

When placed elsewhere, *normally* instead indicates *when* or *where* or *why* you do something ("in normal situations").

> We **normally** walk along the beach every morning, but today the tide is too high.

In your example, there is no confusion because it's clear that *normally* doesn't modify how you do A.  However if you change the word order it does become ambiguous:

> ... doing A **normally** would improve your situation.

There is no way to tell which you mean except from additional context.

> ... doing A normally would improve your situation, **but in this case it didn't.**  (= under normal situations)
>
> ... doing A normally would improve your situation, **but for some reason you chose to do it differently.**  (= in a normal manner)

When speaking you can distinguish which you mean by adding emphasis on *normally*, and pausing before or after.

Side note:  "Refine your situation" is unclear.  It might make sense in the appropriate context, but as is I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Is it like a rule that the meaning depends on where the adverb normally is put?

Comment: @user157323  I don't think it's a *rule*, just logic.  No matter where you put the adverb the meaning *can* be ambiguous, so it helps to place it close to the part of speech it modifies.